# my responsive for small medium mobile is not working?what property shall I need to use

Tags: html, css

my responsive for small medium mobile is not working?what property shall I need to use.I am using firefox.IF I shrink the browser for testing.the logo is not adjusting for mobile device.for testing I have implemented background yellow.The yellow color is coming,but the image is not shrinking for mobile device.I have used width:250px; for small mobile.you can test the link.http://vkacademy.in/res/  .can any one guide what I have do next?

```
my html code:
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="logo"><img src="image/logo.png"  border="0" width="357" height="107"/></div><!--endoflogo-->
<div id="logo1"><a href="#">join as tutor or Institutue</a></div><!--endoflogo1-->
<div id="menu">
<div class="common"><a href="#">About us</a></div>
<div class="common"><a href="#">Department</a></div>
<div class="common"><a href="#">Facilities</a></div>
<div class="common"><a href="#">library</a></div>
<div class="common"><a href="#">Event</a></div>
</div><!--endofmenu-->
</div><!--endofwrapper-->
default.css
@charset "utf-8";
body
{
margin:auto;
background-color:#CCCCCC;
background-repeat:repeat;
}
#wrapper
{
width:1000px;
height:auto;
margin:auto;
}

#logo
{
width:500px;
height:100px;
float:left;
}
#logo1
{
width:400px;
height:80px;
float:left;
padding-left:50px;
padding-right:50px;
background-color:#FF00FF;
}

#menu
{
width:1000px;
height:45px;
float:left;
}

.common
{
width:200px;
height:42px;
padding-top:8px;
float:left;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
text-align:center;
}


mobile.css
    @media only screen and (max-width:530px)
    {
    #wrapper
        {
        width:260px;
        background-repeat:repeat;
        }

        #logo
        {
        width:260px;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:#FFFF00;
        }

        #logo1
        {
        width:160px;
        padding-left:50px;
        padding-right:50px;
        }

      #menu
      {
      width:260px;
      height:auto;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your image is not shrinking properly is because by selecting only #logo you've only set width for the container of the image, and not the image itself.

If you add this css:

```
#logo img { width:260px; }
```

into your responsive rule, then you should be good to go!

Additionally, if you want to change the image for tablet devices then I'd recommend using something like this:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width : 768px) 
  and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  /* tablet CSS here */
}
```

Additional info on media queries can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Comment: Yes It is working.you check the same link.Same thing If I want to make for big mobile and tablet what media queries I need to write. I am think of how to make the menu.if I click an image.like toggle effect

Comment: I updated my answer to include an acceptable media query for tablet devices.

Comment: Yes I got this my final query is how to make a menu.when I click an image it has come with toggle effect.or generally how do I bring the menu.I don't have any idea about that.can you write for small device.

Comment: can you help me with menu css for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is really **NOT** good to use `px` in responsive designs ...

Just add this property to your css

```
img {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Well my advise is to use `%` and `em` everywhere ... **AVOID `px`**.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your mobile css

```
#logo img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/scmopp81/